# Identify end of for loop in velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a velocity template something like this.

```
foreach ($field in {fields})
//some code here
end
```

I have to validate that `$field`  is not used outside of foreach loop. So I want to identify the end of for loop. How can I do that ?

Comment: This doesn't look like Java...

Comment: @ChrisTaylor It's not. It's [Velocity Template Language](http://velocity.apache.org/), commonly used with Java-backed web applications.

Answer (score 0):

**As per the documentation**

If you want to stop looping in a foreach from within your template, you can now use the [`#break`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#break) directive to stop looping at any time:

```
    ## list first 5 customers only
    foreach( $customer in $customersList)
       //instead of 5, you can give listsize-1 to find last loop
        if( $foreach.count > 5) 
            //Write your logic
            break
        end
    end
```

Please adopt the above logic for your case. Hope this helps. For better clarity, read the [documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html).